# Cannot connect to SQL Server instance in .net core 2.1 app

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

There are many answers around this question - I haven't been able to solve my problem with them.

I just created a .net core web api and I am attempting to instantiate an `SqlConnection`. When I call open on it I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

At this point I have no idea why. I have tried every connection string format I could find and currently I am using this:

```
Data Source=(volodb);Initial Catalog=volo;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=localUser;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

This is the exact connection string I found by connecting via Visual Studio SQL object tool, and it still isn't working for me.

Background: Named pipes enabled, tcp/ip enabled, alias setup via SQL Server configuration manager including on the 32-bit option, the default port is 1433, server, server agent, and server browser running/been restarted. Still not working.

`netstat -a -n` shows the port in a listening state.

It's all working via SQL Server Management Studio as well.

Comment: Do the Paranthesis (MyServer) force a local lookup but ignore the name.   If the Connection string was Data Source=volodb  or  Data Source=(local)  would it work?   Is volo a reserved word for local in SQL servers codebase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a mixture of a syntax error in my first query giving a very poor error message that made it seem like it was a connection issue, and needing to go back to the standard connection string...